# What is SS_X_JSESSIONID and when is it created?

Tags: java, weblogic, jsessionid

We have deployed our web application in weblogic and two cookies are created:
jsessionid
ss_x_jsessionid

What is the meaning of the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the SS_X_JSESSIONID cookie is generated by WebCenter Sites as JSESSIONID and passed as such to Remote Satellite Server. It contains the session id for Sites. Remote Satellite Server then passes it to the user as SS_X_JSESSIONID, along with Remote Satellite Server's own JSESSIONID.

Answer (score 0):

When you access your web application through a web browser, it stores cookies as per the headers setting in you web app.

For cookie description, for eg on Google chrome,

1. Open Settings and click **Show advanced settings**.
2. Under **Privacy** heading, click on **Content Settings** button. A popup will open.
3. Under the heading **Cookies**, click on **All cookies and site data**. This option will show all the details related to cookies and other site data stored on the browser.

Check for your cookie name. It will show the details.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. What I am asking is about what component is creating that cookie (weblogic, webcenter sites, etc) and what is the difference between jsessionid and ss_x_jsessionid.

Comment: I dont think that weblogic will be creating it. It might be some configuration related to cookie in your application that is creating it. Can't tell how it is different from JSESSIONID